# Springdata elasticsearch support for scaled_float field type

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is elasticsearch springdata module supports scaled_float es type?

Comment: I'm forked spring data es repo, and cherry pick commit with missing data types from version 4.0.0.Mx to version 3.x.x - its works for now.

Answer (score 1):

From version 4.0 on, this is supported